# Where can I get reliable short-term programming development help ?

Tags: job-offer, work-experience

Recently , I tried using CraigsList to hire someone for Java help. I offered large money ($80/hour).

Sadly, the  guy that I found turned out a dud .

Where can I get reliable short-term Java development assistance ? Is there a legal, reliable way to hire coders by-the-hour

Comment: Depending on the complexity of what you need, you might try the computer science department at your local university.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Where can I get reliable short-term Java development assistance ? Is
>   there a legal, reliable way to hire coders by-the-hour?

In my part of the world there are many thousands of agencies who would be happy to help.

A quick Google search should easily find many.